# How do I pass a variable as first argument to a subroutine only if it is defined?

Tags: perl

Does anyone have a better (shorter) way of writing the following logic in Perl?
Seems abit cumbersome as it is now... And i don't want to pass any excessive variables to either of the subroutines...

```
#!perl
use Data::Dumper;

my $var = "ok";
my $bar = 1;
my ($a, $b, $c) = (1,2,3);

if ($var eq "ok") {
    if (defined $bar) {
        foo1($bar, $a);
    }
    else {
        foo1($a);
    }
}
elsif ($var eq "not_ok") {
    if (defined $bar) {
        foo2($bar, $a, $b);
    }
    else {
        foo2($a, $b);
    }
}
else {
    if (defined $bar) {
        foo3($bar, $a, $b, $c);
    }
    else {
        foo3($a, $b, $c);
    }
}

sub foo1 {print Dumper @_}
sub foo2 {print Dumper @_}
sub foo3 {print Dumper @_}
```

Comment: _[Dan F.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/718269/dan-f)_: Please use words that befit a public forum. I have replaced the word.

Answer (score 7):

```
use 5.010;
foo( $bar // (), $a, $b, $c );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
foo(grep { defined } $where, $is, $pancakes, $house);
```

That will filter out any undefined values in the argument list.

Comment: _[mu is too short](http://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short)_: Thank you for not using the inappropriate word (which was present in the question) in your answer. **++**

Comment: @Alan: Thanks, I do try to watch my language in polite company. OTOH, you're a couple steps closer to your Copy Editor badge now and you get to feel good about doing a good deed :)

Comment: _[mu is too short](http://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short)_: Nice to know that. Yes, it feels good. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said anything about what your actual foo1/2/3 subs do, so this may not be appropriate to your case, but my first impulse would be to modify them so that they simply ignore the first argument if it's `undef`.  This would then allow you to simply call `foo1($bar, $a, $b, $c);` without worrying about whether `$bar` is defined or not.

```
sub foo1 {
  shift unless defined $_[0];
  # ...do other stuff now that any leading undef has been removed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($var eq "ok") {
    foo1(defined $bar ? $bar : (), $a);
}
elsif ($var eq "not_ok") {
    foo2(defined $bar ? $bar : (), $a, $b);
}
else {
    foo3(defined $bar ? $bar : (), $a, $b, $c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to build your argument list:

```
my @args = ($a);
unshift(@args, $bar) if defined $bar;

if ($var eq "ok") {
    foo1(@args);
}
elsif($var eq "not_ok") {
    foo2(@args, $b);
}
else {
    foo3(@args, $b, $c);
}
```